# django imagefield model

Tags: django, imagefield

how can I define it in the model if I want the image to save in the path 'img/'currentdateMonthYear_ + category_+ the given name. The category depend on what I choose?

currently I describe my model as such:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    title       = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description     = models.TextField()
    hits        = models.IntegerField()
    timestamp   = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    thumb       = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos...
    tag         = models.ForeignKey(Tag)
    artist      = models.ForeignKey(User)
    storage     = models.ForeignKey(Storage)
    market      = models.ForeignKey(Market)
    Category    = models.ForeignKey(Category)
    Log         = models.ForeignKey(Log)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide a callable to upload_to.

```
def get_image_path(instance, filename):
    return os.path.join('img', str(instance.category), filename)

class Image(models.Model):
    thumb = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_path)
```